# Pan sharpening using R

Tags: raster, r, pansharpening

I want to pan sharpen my Landsat8 scene (according to FIHS algorithm, see [here](http://www.mdpi.com/2220-9964/3/2/507/pdf)).

According to the paper the following equation should do the pansharpening:

```
MS_high <- MS_low + (pan - I)
```

"MS_high" is the pansharpened MS band and "MS_low" the original MS band.

The *I* image is intended to be a simulated image of the Pan band at the spatial resolution of the MS bands. Spatial details from Pan are obtained by subtracting the lower resolution *I* band from the higher resolution Pan band.

When doing the substraction (Pan - I) the following output occurs:

> Error in compareRaster(e1, e2, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, crs = TRUE,  : 
>     different resolution

Does anyone used the FIHS pansharpening algorithm in R so far?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do the two rasters (Pan and I) have the same resolution? I.e. did you properly resample the I channel first?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So you think I should do the following steps: 1. resample I to 15m with function resample(I, pan) and then do in a second step the substraction pan (15m resolution) - I (15m resolution)?

Comment: That's what reading the error message : *different resolution* suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `panSharp` from the **satellite** package. The function works with regular 'RasterLayer' objects (refer to the second example in `?panSharp`, which is also shown below) and supports inputs of different spatial resolution, i.e. internally performs `raster::resample`. The only arguments `panSharp` requires are a target layer (`x`) and the panchromatic channel (`pan`).

```
## sample data
path <- system.file("extdata", package = "satellite")
files <- list.files(path, pattern = glob2rx("LC8*.tif"), full.names = TRUE)
sat <- satellite(files)

# target channel
rst_b001n <- getSatDataLayer(sat, "B001n")
# panchromatic channel
rst_panch <- getSatDataLayer(sat, getSatBCDEFromType(sat, type = "PCM"))

## pan-sharpen target layer
rst_b001n_ps <- panSharp(rst_b001n, rst_panch)
```

[image: pansharpen]

Comment: Is panSharp available in the latest version of "satellite"?

Comment: Pansharpening and histogram matching have been moved to [**satelliteTools**](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/satelliteTools) a while ago. You can install it via `remotes::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/satelliteTools")`.